# Ng-repeat finished refire after filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to launch a function everytime the ng-repeat is finished,
I've got the following so far:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.friends = [{
    name: 'John',
    phone: '555-1276'
  }, {
    name: 'Mary',
    phone: '800-BIG-MARY'
  }, {
    name: 'Mike',
    phone: '555-4321'
  }, {
    name: 'Adam',
    phone: '555-5678'
  }, {
    name: 'Julie',
    phone: '555-8765'
  }, {
    name: 'Juliette',
    phone: '555-5678'
  }]

  $scope.test = function() {
    console.log('test');
  }
});

app.directive('onFinishRender', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      if (scope.$last === true) {
        scope.$evalAsync(attr.onFinishRender);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label>Search:
    <input ng-model="searchText">
  </label>
  <table id="searchTextResults">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText" on-finish-render="test()">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

This fires the function once, but how would you modify this to make it work every time the filter get's applied?

[Plunker version](http://plnkr.co/edit/cCAWldxfuwFHZyLfxcKZ?p=preview)

Comment: you can write custom filter and pass this function as callback

Comment: That is what I did ... it just fires only once

Comment: nope, you create custom _directive_, i say about custom _filter_

Comment: Ow, sorry read that wrong, going to look into it

Comment: something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/uqhRmVrtBSXspBk8cFN2?p=preview), but in this case filter call twice

Comment: @Grundy, olmost perfect! now I need to pass some vars :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89146/discussion-between-grundy-and-kiwi).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correct, you would use ng-change directive to your input box of search.

Use this :

```
<input ng-model="searchText" ng-change="test();">
```

Comment: In the example this could be used, but in the setup where I need it, the content is loaded async (forgot to mention that, my bad), so this could get called to early

Comment: @Kiwi, so can you provide more relevant sample?

Comment: @Kiwi "so this could get called to early" ?

Answer (score 0):

I have added scope to the directive. also ngRepeat's $last is sent through the scope variable. And changes to scope.last are being watched using scope.$watch so whenever list changes scope.last will change and then return true at the last step. This will run whenever there is a change in collection.

See the updated Plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/68XXIQyo2rkUP4uj6bnI?p=preview

HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head> 

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

  <label>Search:
    <input ng-model="searchText">
  </label>
  <table id="searchTextResults">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText" on-finish-render="test()" last="$last">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.friends = [{
    name: 'John',
    phone: '555-1276'
  }, {
    name: 'Mary',
    phone: '800-BIG-MARY'
  }, {
    name: 'Mike',
    phone: '555-4321'
  }, {
    name: 'Adam',
    phone: '555-5678'
  }, {
    name: 'Julie',
    phone: '555-8765'
  }, {
    name: 'Juliette',
    phone: '555-5678'
  }]

  $scope.test = function() {
    console.log('test');
  }
});

app.directive('onFinishRender', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      onFinishRender: '&',
      last: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch('last', function(){
          if (scope.last === true) {
          scope.onFinishRender();
        }  
      });

    }
  }
});
```